# How to Remove cart products if a specific product is added in cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, downloadable

This is my onpage.phtml page to get product id. I need to remove all other products in cart except the mention product id below if this product is on cart.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {// product id 
    $it[] = $item->getProductId();
}
if (in_array(483, $it)){
  //What logic to make here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach function to this:

```
$quoteId = $cart->getQuote()->getId();
$quoteModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');

foreach($items as $item) {// product id 
    $itemId = $item->getItemId();
    if($itemId == "483") {
        $quoteItem = $quoteModel->load($quoteId);
        $quoteItem->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it is not working.

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me, I have only added the solution, please add class and other required stuff

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
```

Constructor

```
public function __construct(
    Session $checkoutSession,
    Item $quoteItem
) {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->quoteItem = $quoteItem;
}
```

Code to remove item and recalculate totals, $itemId is the product id to be removed from cart

```
$allItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    $itemId = $item->getItemId();
    $quoteItem=$this->quoteItem->load($itemId);
    $quoteItem->delete();

    $currentQuote=$this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $currentQuote->setTriggerRecollect(1);
    $currentQuote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```